# How to find inner li's class and change upper one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Let me show my problem with simple code.

```
<ul class="page-sidebar-menu">
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li> <!-- I want that jquery find the class active in it and add it to here -->
        <ul>
            <li class="active"></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

after that, I want it looks like that;

```
<ul class="page-sidebar-menu">
    <li></li>
    .
    .
    .
    <li></li>
    <li class="active"> <!-- That, I want -->
        <ul>
            <li class="active"></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It just in one li has it, and I have to add it the upper one...

How can I find the `class` called `actvie` and add it to parents `li` ?

----OK thank guys, this my solution ----
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('li.active').closest('ul.page-sidebar-menu > li').addClass('active');
        $('li.active').closest('ul.page-sidebar-menu > li').find('a').append('');
    });

It works with `closest('ul.page-sidebar-menu > li')`, otherwise it finds itself. (checked it with `removeClass` and removed it's own class.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest)

```
$('li.active').closest('li').addClass('active');
```

Comment: I've change it a bit with adding `ul.page-sidebar-menu > li`, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.closest()`:

```
$(".active").closest("li").addClass("active");
```